# Write a C program to print all numbers between 1 to 100 which divided by a specified number and the remainder will be 3

Tags: c

When I run this code, 3 is shown in the first line on the terminal. Why is it being like this?

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, num;

    printf("\nInput an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i%num == 3) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what value did you input into num?

Comment: Why do you think the first number which, when divided by any number greater than 3, leaves a remainder of 3 shouldn't be 3?

Comment: Input an integer:48 result=>  3,51,99

Comment: Well, 0 × 48 + 3 = 3, no? (By the way, you don't need to loop over all 100 integers to solve this.)

Comment: You are getting 3 as 3%48 is 3. So if don't want 3 to be printed change the if condition to `if ((i > num) && (i % num == 3))`

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have mentioned

```
if (i%num == 3) {
      printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

first `output 3` is **not a error**. For an example if you insert integer number as 5

```
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
```

likewise

```
11 % 5 = 1
12 % 5 = 2
13 % 5 = 3
```

If you want **remove** number 3, your input number **must be** lower than `i` value.Then you can try this

```
if (i % num == 3 && i > num) {
       printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

- If your input number is 4

  `output -: 7, 11, 15....`
- If your input number is 5

  `output -: 8, 13, 18....`

Comment: `If a<b: a%b == a`